# React Visible + Add class

Tags: reactjs, class, addition

It's works:

```js
var onChange = function (isVisible) {
    console.log('Element is now %s', isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    if(isVisible = 'visible'){
        //here I need add class
    }
};
```

And the VisibilitySensor is in inside component **Needs** in div className =**Need**.

```xml
<VisibilitySensor onChange={onChange}/>
```

The code is working well, I can see console.log after rendering.
So. what is my problem.

I wan't add class **animated fadeInUp**. **if isVisible = 'visible'**

How can I add this class to **Needs** className React?

If it help, here is all code:

https://pastebin.com/bnTKbXC4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a refactoring of your code, I'm not sure if it's going to work or not.

```
class Needs extends React.Component{


    constructor(props)
    {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            Need: 'Need'
            };

        this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    }

    onChange(isVisible)
    {
        console.log('Element is now %s', isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
        if(isVisible = 'visible')
        {
            this.setState( {Need : 'Need ' + ' animated fadeIn' } );
        }
        else
        {
            this.setState( {Need : 'Need ' } );
        }
    }

    render()
    {
        var VisibilitySensor = require('react-visibility-sensor');

        return(
            <div className ={this.state.Need}>

                <VisibilitySensor onChange={this.onChange}/>

                <div className ="Section_Text">
                    <h1>Solutions tailored to your needs</h1>
                    <p><b>Creating experience in real & digital world.</b></p>
                    <p>
                        Cooperation with a lot of designers, photographers,
                        programmist & specialists from various field allows
                        to create effective solutions for your business goals.</p>
                </div>

                <img src={bulb} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank You I modify if:
       if(isVisible)

And it's working well, hey how can I add display:none in it? 

       {
           this.setState( {Need : 'Need ' + ' animated fadeInUp' } );
       }

Comment: First in the **constructor** change the state to `this.state = {Need: 'Need', style:{}};` and onChange method inside **else statement** set the state `this.setState( {Need : 'Need ', style:{display: "none"} } );` when it's invisible and don't forget to add a new attribute to the div  `<div className ={this.state.Need} style={this.state.style}>`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know whether you are managing state or not. But it looks like this is stateful component then why not.

```js
// just below this line -  class Needs extends React.Component 
state = {
    NeedsBrother: false // setting this variable to false initially
}
```

and then

```js
var onChange = function (isVisible) {
    console.log('Element is now %s', isVisible ? 'visible' : 'hidden');
    if(isVisible = 'visible'){
        this.setState(prevState => {
            NeedsBrother: true
        })
    }
};
```

and in your render function

```
<div className={`Need ${this.state.NeedsBrother}`}>
```

Comment: 1) Its incorrect syntax in React :-( I can't using code like this : <div className={Need: true, NeedsBrother: false}>

2) It's true I should create and manage state, but I don't know where I should do it

Comment: try again i have edited , try to inspect this div and see what's there

Comment: <div className={this.state.NeedsBrother === true ? 'Need NeedsBrother' : 'Need'}> In case that doesnt work , this will work

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'NeedsBrother' of null


Hmm, i edited this, and the name of div was "false" and "true"

Comment: Now code is :
https://pastebin.com/D4Ti2hyQ

and error:
Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Comment: If you are using constructor method you need to bind your method . this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this). Put this into your constructor

Comment: Ok,
https://pastebin.com/aKRBGBBc
now I edit this code and still have an error: Uncaught TypeError: this.setState is not a function

Answer (score 0):

Have you declared NeedsBrother as a state variable.

```
this.state={NeedsBrother:false}
```